# Issue setting the picture property of an image on a VBA form

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 pictures on a vba form.
The images are (picture1, picture2, and selectedImage)

The VBA sets either picture1 or picture2 equal to selectedImage.  Picture1 and Picture2 initialize to (none), and selectedImageis set to a local bitfile.

```
Private Sub updatePicture(position As Integer)

'This code works when un-commented out and run
    'Picture1.Picture = selectedImage.Picture

'This code does not update the images 
    If position = 1 Then
        Picture1.Picture = selectedImage.Picture
    ElseIf position = 2 Then
        Picture2.Picture = selectedImage.Picture
    End If

End Sub
```

I debugged and confirmed position = 1, and the line 'Picture1.Picture = selectedImage.Picture' is being run, yet the image is not being updated...

Any help would be welcome.  Using excel 2013.

Comment: Please update your question to clarify whether the Image control is called `selectedPicture` or 'selectedImage`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the code is correct... the image control is selectedImage

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is often associated with the fact that a change to an `Image` picture does not fire an event. Assuming that you're definitely passing a 1 or 2 into the procedure (you should check for sure that you are), there are several ways you could handle the repaint issue:

One would be to add the `Repaint` method at the bottom of your code, so your procedure would read:

```
If position = 1 Then
    Picture1.Picture = selectedImage.Picture
ElseIf position = 2 Then
    Picture2.Picture = selectedImage.Picture
End If
Me.Repaint
```

However, this will repaint your entire `Userform` and can cause flicker if you are updating the picture rapidly (eg on a progress monitor or multiple click handling) or have a huge `Userform`.

The other way would be to create an event and run your new picture through that event. I can't say this from a position of authority, but my impression is that the `Event` will coerce a repaint and appears only to refresh that part of the `Userform` where a change is detected, so my experience is that this method is far smoother.

The way you'd do this is very simple. You insert a new `Class` and suitably name it (I called mine *clsPicHandler*). The code within that class could be a little as this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Event PictureChanged(img As MSForms.Image, pic As Object)

Public Sub SetPicture(img As MSForms.Image, pic As Object)

    If img Is Nothing Or pic Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If img.Picture Is pic Then Exit Sub

    RaiseEvent PictureChanged(img, pic)

End Sub
```

The code behind your `Userform`, then, would trigger and handle the event, like so:

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mPicHandler As clsPicHandler

Public Sub UpdatePicture(position As Integer)
    If position = 1 Then
        mPicHandler.SetPicture Picture1, selectedImage.Picture
    ElseIf position = 2 Then
        mPicHandler.SetPicture Picture2, selectedImage.Picture
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub mPicHandler_PictureChanged(img As MSForms.Image, pic As Object)
    img.Picture = pic
    DoEvents
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set mPicHandler = New clsPicHandler
End Sub
```